# How to load new component on button click

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have a form, when user taps on `Login` button, i want to load a new component, and disable the current component.  I read about `react-router`,but it looks like i can use them for navigation.

This is my code.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <HeaderComponent />      
        <header className="App-header">
            <LoginComponent/> 
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

when user taps on `Login button`, this method in `LoginComponent.js` gets called.

```
  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Login");
  }
```

Now i can successfully prints the `Log` message, but i am unable to understand how to load a different component at this time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want it to be on a separate page you can use a conditional in your render, and change the state on the submit.

Example:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    componentShown: false    
   }
  render() {
    return (

      <div className="App">
        <HeaderComponent />      
        <header className="App-header">

           {this.state.componentShown ? <ComponentToRender /> : 
            <LoginComponent/> }    
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

And on your submit just change the state.

```
handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ componentShown: true })
  }
```